# Excel: Search column for value that exists between a set range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem with excel. I have a column that has several dates and I would like to check if that column contains a date that is in between two separate dates.

For example: Column A has a number of dates and B1 has a past date and C1 contains the current date. I would like to check if Column A has a date that is in between the dates in B1 and C1.

Is this even possible in excel?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into the `coutifs` function to see if any data exists.

`=countifs(A:A,">=" & B1, A:A, "<" & C1)`

will tell you if the data exists.

If you just want a flag you could use

`=--countifs(A:A,">=" & B1, A:A, "<" & C1)>0`

Comment: The second formula worked perfectly! Thanks so much! Just on a side note, is it possible to change the output value to be something else other then TRUE/FALSE?

Comment: you would just need to wrap it in an if statement `=if(--countif(A:A,">=" & B1, A:A, "<" & C1)>0,"This is True","This is False")`

Answer (score 1):

Because dates are just numbers you can simply compare them to each other:

```
=IF(AND($A1 > $B$1; $A1 < $C$1); "TRUE"; "FALSE")
```

Comment: =If(AND(A:A > B1; A:A < C1); "TRUE"; "FALSE")  This came up as an error.

Comment: The problem is that you use a range as input for the `AND` function. This function does only check whether the cell is in the given range...

Comment: Is there any way to have it check the entire column for a value that would be between B1 and C1? Instead of just a single cell?

Comment: I think you will need an extra column where you will check for each cell if it is in range, then do a count on the cells with TRUE value.

Comment: I did =COUNTIF(c1:c10,"TRUE") on the column with that has my If Statements and it came up 0 even though two cells have "TRUE." Do you think it fails because I am checking a column that has formulas instead of just the value "TRUE"?